# Swift 3 to Swift 4 kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView

Tags: swift, xcode9-beta

I'm using a third party library and I'm getting errors which I don't understand (I'm new to Swift).

Here's the code:

```
final class ReusableCollection<Reusable>: Sequence where Reusable: NSObject {
var pairs = [Address: Reusable]()
var addresses = Set<Address>()

var objects: LazyMapCollection<[Address: Reusable], Reusable> {
    return pairs.values
}

func contains(_ member: Address) -> Bool {
    return addresses.contains(member)
}

@discardableResult
func insert(_ newMember: Address) -> (inserted: Bool, memberAfterInsert: Address) {
    return addresses.insert(newMember)
}

func subtract(_ other: Set<Address>) {
    addresses.subtract(other)
}

subscript(key: Address) -> Reusable? {
    get {
        return pairs[key]
    }
    set(newValue) {
        pairs[key] = newValue
    }
}

func makeIterator() -> LazyMapIterator<DictionaryIterator<Address, Reusable>, Reusable> {
    return pairs.values.makeIterator()
}
```

On the `return pairs.values` I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot convert return expression of type 'Dictionary.Values' to return type 'LazyMapCollection<[Address : Reusable], Reusable>'"

And on the last line I'm getting this error:

> "Ambiguous reference to member 'makeIterator()'"

Further more I have this:

```
let mergedCells = dataSource.mergedCells(in: self)
let mergedCellLayouts: [Location: CellRange] = { _ in
    var layouts = [Location: CellRange]()
```

And here I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> _' to specified type '[Location : CellRange]'"

Any idea? I've made some research but I haven't been able to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

This problem was fixed at `0.7.3`. Please use the latest version.